# SageMaker Studio domain creation fails due to KMS permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-kms

## Question

Please help understand the cause and solution for the problem.

## Problem

SageMaker Studio domain creation fails due to KMS permissions. The IAM Role specified to the SageMaker arn:aws:iam::316725000538:role/SageMaker has the permissions for KMS required as specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html.

> Domain creation failed
> Unable to create Amazon EFS for domain 'd-1dq5c9rpkswy' because you don't have permissions to use the KMS key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:316725000538:key/1e2dbf9d-daa0-408d-a290-1633b615c54f'. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html for required permissions for CreateDomain action.

[image] tells the IAM permissions

## IAM Permission for CreateDomain action

- [Amazon SageMaker API Permissions: Actions, Permissions, and Resources Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html)

[image]

The IAM permission required for the CreateDomain action have been attached to the IAM role.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when trying to use the aws/s3 key. I created my own Customer Managed Key (CMK) and it worked just fine.
I think it's related to the AWS assigned policy on the aws/s3 key.

This part:

```
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "kms:CallerAccount": "120455730103",
            "kms:ViaService": "s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        }
```

I don't think SageMaker meets the kms:ViaService condition.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from SageMakerFullAccess we need to create a new policy and attach that to your user.

Create a new policy with below json -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:CreateUserProfile",
                "sagemaker:CreateModel",
                "sagemaker:CreateLabelingJob",
                "sagemaker:CreateFlowDefinition",
                "sagemaker:CreateDomain",
                "sagemaker:CreateAutoMLJob",
                "sagemaker:CreateProcessingJob",
                "sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob",
                "sagemaker:CreateNotebookInstance",
                "sagemaker:CreateCompilationJob",
                "sagemaker:CreateImage",
                "sagemaker:CreateMonitoringSchedule",
                "sagemaker:RenderUiTemplate",
                "sagemaker:UpdateImage",
                "sagemaker:CreateHyperParameterTuningJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```